# ActiveMQ Spring client: How to change processors pool?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We have ActiveMQ 5.10 and JMS client in Spring 4.0 through Maven like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

with configuration in code by instantiating ActiveMQConnectionFactory.

We want to limit throughput of queue processing, keeping inserting in high volume or unlimited.

How do I setup the connector the way that it can use 1000 outbound connections but only no more than 2 threads to process messages from the queue?

Comment: show your current configuration please. [The doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) is pretty explicit about it unless I misunderstood your question (check the `concurrency` attribute). Note that you can set it on the `jms:listener` element as from Spring 4.1. If you upgrade you could also use the new annotated endpoint infrastructure.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll can you please post your answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) is pretty explicit about it unless I misunderstood your question (check the `concurrency` attribute).

Note that you can set it on the `jms:listener element` as from Spring 4.1 only. If you upgrade you could also use the new *annotated endpoint infrastructure*.